# How many ways we can choose 3 numbers from 1 to 300 when the summation of the 3 numbers is divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics

So the solution in my book is,
$$x\ \ \ \ \ x+1\ \ \ \ x+2$$
$$1\ \ \ \ \ 2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$4\ \ \ \ \ 5\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$7\ \ \ \ \ 8\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 9\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$.\ \ \ \ \ .\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$.\ \ \ \ \ .\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$298\ \ \ 299\ \ \ \ \ 300\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

- Chosing any 3 numbers from column $x,\ x+1,\ x+2$ = ${100\choose 1}*{100\choose 1}*{100\choose 1}$
- Chosing any 3 numbers from column $x$ = ${100\choose 3}$
- Chosing any 3 numbers from column $x+1$ = ${100\choose 3}$
- Chosing any 3 numbers from column $x+2$ = ${100\choose 3}$

So the total number = ${100\choose 1}*{100\choose 1}*{100\choose 1}+{100\choose 3}+{100\choose 3}+{100\choose 3}$

My question is why this method works? Is this method only for 3 divisibility or I can apply it on other cases? If yes, then how?

Comment: I guess one approach is to think about how you can add three numbers together so that the sum is divisible by $3$. So you have to think in mod $3$. The options, therefore, are (in modulo 3):
$$
1 + 2 +3 \equiv 0 \mod{3}
$$
$$
1 + 1 +1 \equiv 0 \mod{3}
$$
$$
2 + 2 +2 \equiv 0 \mod{3}
$$
$$
3 + 3 +3 \equiv 0 \mod{3}
$$
and these correspond exactly to the bullet points that you have written.

Comment: Do the selected numbers need to be distinct?

Comment: @PJK the book's given solution implies that yes they do and that order of the selection doesn't matter.

Comment: "*Does this method work only for 3 divisibility or can I apply it on other cases?*"  Similar solutions work for other cases, for example if you wanted to get the sum to be an even number using three numbers, you can break the available numbers to choose from into even and odd numbers and you recognize that you either need to select three even numbers or one even and two odd numbers giving a total of $\binom{150}{3}+\binom{150}{1}\binom{150}{2}$.  Here, again, we just need to break into cases based on the possible ways in which we can arrive at a sum of the desired type.